# Voice speak out with amount like paytm

Tags: android, kotlin, paytm

I want integrate the algorithm which is used by paytm to speak amount like 20rs done successfully. so i want to implement same functionality can anyone suggest that how i can achieve this with india voice accent in android or kotlin.

Comment: Checkout Google Dialogflow https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow

Comment: hey @Sneha have you got any workaround..?

Answer (score 2):

You can use speak() method of `android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech` class
and using the same you can convert a text to speech (audio)

Comment: Yes i have tried that but with that i am unable achieve Indian accent. Present i am able achieve default US accent. Actually i am trying this in ingenico terminal and it is banking related so in this terminal only Pico TTS engine is there so that, this is not supporting any other accents other than default.